# Apple Event Handler Failure while trying to growl

Tags: ruby, rb-appscript, sourceforge-appscript

I'm trying to growl from Ruby/Appscript, based on this sample Applescript code:

```
tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
    set the enabledNotificationsList to {"Mail Notification"}
    register as application "MailWidgetGrowlHelper" all notifications enabledNotificationsList default notifications enabledNotificationsList icon of application "Mail.app"
    notify with name "Mail Notification" title (item 1 of argv) description (item 2 of argv) & return & return & (item 3 of argv) application name "MailWidgetGrowlHelper" icon of application "Mail.app" without sticky
end tell
```

My code looks like this:

```
GH = app("GrowlHelperApp.app")

enabledNotifications = "AppscriptMessage"

GH.register(:as_application => "AppscriptHelper",
    :all_notifications => enabledNotifications,
    :default_notifications => enabledNotifications)
```

the last call fails with:

> Appscript::CommandError: CommandError OSERROR: -10000 MESSAGE: Apple event handler failed.

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'Oh. The enabledNotifications should be an Array, not just a string.